Unable to build the project with opentelementery extention
I have spring boot project which is on version 2.7.7. We have some dependency on otel telementery for that we have used some part of build.gradle like below.
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "8.3.5"
    id "io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.muzzle-generation" version "2.10.0-alpha-SNAPSHOT"
    id "io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.muzzle-check" version "2.10.0-alpha-SNAPSHOT"
}

group 'io.opentelemetry.example'
version '1.0'

ext {
    versions = [
            otelSdkExtensionAutoconfigure: "1.41.0",
            otelJavaAgent                : "2.9.0-SNAPSHOT",
            otelInstrumentationApi       : "2.9.0-SNAPSHOT",
            otelExtensionApi             : "2.9.0-alpha-SNAPSHOT",
            otelJavaagentTooling         : "2.9.0-alpha-SNAPSHOT",
            otelInstrumentationAgentApi  : "2.9.0-alpha-SNAPSHOT"
    ]

I am getting below issue for building the project
Could not resolve com.github.johnrengelman:shadow:8.1.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.github.johnrengelman.shadow:com.github.johnrengelman.shadow.gradle.plugin:8.1.1
      > Module 'com.github.johnrengelman:shadow' has been rejected:
           Cannot select module with conflict on capability 'com.github.johnrengelman:shadow:8.1.1' also provided by [com.gradleup.shadow:shadow-gradle-plugin:8.3.5(runtimeElements)]
   > Could not resolve com.gradleup.shadow:shadow-gradle-plugin:8.3.5.
     Required by:
         project : > io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.muzzle-generation:io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.muzzle-generation.gradle.plugin:2.10.0-alpha-SNAPSHOT:20241113.033534-92 > io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:gradle-plugins:2.10.0-alpha-SNAPSHOT:20241113.033534-92
      > Module 'com.gradleup.shadow:shadow-gradle-plugin' has been rejected:
           Cannot select module with conflict on capability 'com.github.johnrengelman:shadow:8.3.5' also provided by [com.github.johnrengelman:shadow:8.1.1(runtimeElements)]

i have tried with updating version to 8.3.5 still it is coming

If you have Spring Boot then why are you adding the com.github.johnrengelman.shadow? That is not needed as Spring Boot already creates a fat runnable jar. So ditch that plugin.

@M.Deinum It is asking me to add in the build.gradle file. I have tried with 8.3.5 and 8.3.0 but getting issue as not found

What is it? Anyway don't as that breaks Spring Boot.

@M.Deinum We have tried to exclude plugin com.github.johnrengelman:shadow from build.gradle file but it does not help. It failed with error as com.github.johnrengelman:shadow not found. Can you please help on how to resolve this issue?

There is another fatjar plugin in there as well (judging from the error) ditch that. You are using Spring Boot, and the Spring Boot gradle plugin already creates a fatjar. Don't add other plugins that do that as well.

@M.Deinum We have tried to remove plugin but it failed with different error.

Just commenting that you get another error without specifying the error doesn't really help. Judging from what you posted here you have multiple plugins trying to create a fatjar which are competing with each other. You are probably following tutorials and manuals which are for use without spring boot and trying to shoehorn it into a Spring Boot based application.
